# Can we use External Id to update a record using update statement?

Tags: update, upsert

I am trying to update a record using an external Id in Apex. The syntax i have tried is given below.

```
update caserecs SAP_Notification_Number__c;
```

But the above statement throws compiler error. If i substituted update with upsert it works fine. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

Update and Upsert are two different Data Manipulation Languague (DML) statements.

Update will only use the ID of records for matching.  If it finds a match it will update the record with the data you've specified.

Insert will only creates new records.  So you can't use insert to update an existing record.

Upsert is a combination of update and insert.  It will update a record if it finds a matching ID or it will create the record if it does not find a matching ID.  In addition, you can specify an External ID field which Upsert can use instead of the standard ID field.

You can get more information here:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_iterable.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_classes_iterable.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is actually pretty simply - update doesn't support external id. So you need to use upsert. Reference here: [Link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_section.htm#apex_dml_update)